# Query doesn't update all rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There's quite big table, more than 10 000 000 rows. It has columns OBJ_ID, DATE_OF_CHANGE, USER. And I added a new column, RECORD_ID, it is empty for now.
I need to update it so RECORD_ID should have numeric values ascending for OBJ_ID and DATE_OF_CHANGE.
I came up with this:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE REC_ID_SEQ
      START WITH 1
      INCREMENT BY 1
      CACHE 100;
    /
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_REC_ID_SEQ
      BEFORE INSERT ON T_HISTORY
      FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      :NEW.RECORD_ID := REC_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    END;
    /

    DECLARE
       O_ID NUMBER := 0;
       S_DATE DATE := SYSDATE;
       HIST_NUM NUMBER := 0;       
       LOOP_COUNT NUMBER := 0;

    BEGIN

      FOR O IN (SELECT ROWID ROW_ID, D.* FROM T_HISTORY D ORDER BY D.OBJ_ID, D.DATE_OF_CHANGE)

      LOOP

          LOOP_COUNT := LOOP_COUNT + 1;
          IF O.OBJ_ID != O_ID OR O.DATE_OF_CHANGE!= S_DATE 
          THEN 
            HIST_NUM := HIST_NUM + 1; 
          END IF;


          UPDATE T_HISTORY T SET T.RECORD_ID = HIST_NUM WHERE T.ROWID = O.ROW_ID;     

          O_ID := O.OBJ_ID;
          S_DATE := O.DATE_OF_CHANGE; 

          IF LOOP_COUNT > 100000 THEN
          COMMIT; LOOP_COUNT := 0;
          END IF;

      END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

But when the command stops working (no errors) I see that about half of rows were not updated. How do I do this the right way?

Comment: This looks REALLY expensive. Why not just `UPDATE <table> SET record_id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY obj_id, date_of_change;` and let it rip.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use `rowid` within this sort of construct @Kaushik - they won't be changing because Oracle's guaranteeing you a read-consistent view of the data. It's probably preferable to use a set-operation as JNevill has said though...

Comment: Kaushik Nayak, this table doesn't have a PK. JNevill, that sounds reasonable, I will try it right  now!

Comment: Unfortunately, JNevill's idea doesn't work. "ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here".

Comment: Looks like it must be done in a subquery in oracle. `UPDATE t1
SET record_id = t1.RowNum
FROM (SELECT obj_id_id, date_of_change, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY obj_id, date_of_change) AS rowNum FROM table) t1` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MERGE` command and `rowid` pseudocolumn as a substitute of primary key:

```
merge into T_HISTORY t
using (
  select rownum as xx, t.* 
  from ( 
    select t.*, rowid as x_rowid 
    from T_HISTORY t
    order by OBJ_ID, DATE_OF_CHANGE
  ) t
) xx
on (xx.x_rowid = t.rowid )
when matched then update
set t.RECORD_ID = xx;
```

Live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aad05/2

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @krokodilko's solution, using analytical function:

```
MERGE INTO t_history t
     USING (SELECT obj_id,
                   date_of_change,
                   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY obj_id, date_of_change) rn
              FROM t_history) r
        ON (t.obj_id = r.obj_id AND t.date_of_change = r.date_of_change)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET t.record_id = r.rn;
```